# Others ways of feature selection aside from sparcity inducing linear algorithms and or random forests

Tags: classification, feature-selection

What are other ways of feature selection within a dataset $X$ for classifying a binary response variable $y$. I know such tools as logistic regression / linear SVMs with an l1 penalty, and sparse PCA. Then in the nonlinear category I only know of random forest / extra trees ensembles using feature importance metrics.

What are other techniques, linear or otherwise that allow one to select a subset of features within $X$ for improving classification metrics.

Aside from standard "off the shelf" techniques like the suggestions above what are more "sophisticated" or involved procedures for feature selection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of **unsupervised methods**, there are some advanced sparse PCA methods that are more suitable for image classification problems. Examples are structured sparse PCA [(Jenatton etal. 2010)](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/sspca_AISTATS2010.pdf). Something that I have some experience with myself is sparse PCA with preserved sparsity (i.e., global/joint sparse PCA); a method that makes sure PCA selects the same features when the reduced dimension is larger than 1. You can find some code samples [here](https://github.com/idnavid/sparse_PCA).

If you're interested in **supervised methods**, many use canonical correlation analysis (CCA) in a least squares framework to find a weight matrix for the features. This is essentially a feature selection scheme.

Quick explanation of CCA: let's say you have *N* sample features of dimension *d* stored in a Matrix **X** and their corresponding *N* binary labels are stored in the matrix **Y**. CCA can provide a pair of weight matrices that minimizes *norm(**XW - YV**)*, where **W** and **V** are the weight matrices. **W** can be viewed as a feature selection matrix.

NOTE:
**Y** doesn't have to be binary when using CCA. Therefore, many have considered using CCA for multi-class classification.

Comment: Do you have any examples of papers where they discuss CCA for feature selection? I have a problem where if my understanding is correct, what you describe could be quite useful.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of papers on this. To give you a quick run-through, this TPAMI paper gives an idea of what I was talking about: 
Sun etal. (2011). Canonical correlation analysis for multilabel classification: A least-squares formulation, extensions, and analysis. IEEE TPAMI, 33(1), 194-200.
Just a heads up, don't get bogged down on their details.

Comment: @astel at the end it comes down to your understanding of CCA and how you fit it to your problem. Just like PCA. I have some notes here, in case it helps you understand things better 
https://github.com/idnavid/misc/blob/master/cca_geometricinterp.ipynb
https://github.com/idnavid/misc/blob/master/comparingSimilarityMeasures.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you comment on what kind of preprocessing the data requires? I typically work with mixed data, including categorical features with large amounts of classes i.e. place of birth, ordinal data such as age, binary data such as sex and rarely continuous data (income is probably the closest to it).  Does this type of data work well with CCA? I read somewhere that categorical data can work once dummy variables are created, but with so many categorical variables with large classes I am worried about having a very sparse matrix.

Comment: @astel like you mentioned, categorical data are a bit tricky to work with. Especially, with linear models. I've seen people report good results, though my personal experience suggests that it might not be the best option to have integer valued features. In any event, it won't hurt to try. Plus CCA doesn't require much preprocessing, other than mean (and potentially variance) normalization.

Answer (score 1):

I have used an auto-encoder for dimensionality reduction.

After the encoder is trained to stability, you can use the bottlenecked (last) hidden layer for obtaining non linear reduction in dimensionality.

Comment: looking at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf due to the suggestion

Comment: [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7d76/b71b700846901ac4ac119403aa737a285e36.pdf) might be useful to your needs.